# Coinbase OAuth works on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, redirect, oauth, localhost, coinbase-api

On my live server i'm getting a `The redirect uri included is not valid.` error message, whereas on my localhost OAuth works ok.

here's the full urls for both:

Localhost:

```
https://coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Faccounts-coinbase%2Foauth&scope=balance+addresses+user+transactions
```

Live server (https://example.com)

```
https://coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Faccounts-coinbase%2Foauth&scope=balance+addresses+user+transactions
```

I'm pretty confident I had the live server OAuth working before. Any ideas why it's failing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my own problem.

The error message, `The redirect uri included is not valid.` does **NOT** accurately reflect the issue at all. What was actually the problem is that my Coinbase OAuth app had a localhost redirect url.

The relevant OAuth redirect url, called a "callback url" is set from this rather hard to find page: https://coinbase.com/oauth/applications.

There I just switched localhost with example.com and it worked.